# Pass enum to method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C#. Recently I got a problem on a project. I need to generate dropdown using enum list. I found a good working [sample](http://nimblegecko.com/aspnetmvc-dropdowns-with-enums/).
But that sample use only one enum my requirement is use this code for any enum. I cant figure it out. My code is

```
        public List<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems()
        {
         var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

         var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Industry)) as Industry[];
         if (enumValues == null)
            return null;

        foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
        {
            // Create a new SelectListItem element and set its 
            // Value and Text to the enum value and description.
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = enumValue.ToString(),
                // GetIndustryName just returns the Display.Name value
                // of the enum - check out the next chapter for the code of this function.
                Text = GetEnumDisplayName(enumValue)
            });
        }

        return selectList;
    }
```

I need to pass any enum to this method. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: can you please add the link to the duplicate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
{
  if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
    throw new ArgumentException("Type parameter must be an enum", nameof(TEnum));

  var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

  var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)) as TEnum[];
  // ...
```

This makes your method *generic*. To call it, use e.g.:

```
GetSelectListItems<Industry>()
```

By the way, I think you could replace the `as TEnum[]` with a "hard" cast to `TEnum[]` and skip that null check:

```
  var enumValues = (TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it's working fine. You saved me.

Comment: How to use as TEnum[] with hard TEnum?